# Display :after content inline with <div>

Tags: html, css

I need to display :after content inline with a `<div>`. For a slider I'm using (Royal Slider) I have the navigation outputting numerically. I need the word "PHOTOS" to display after that output, but inline with it.

Currently my code outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
PHOTOS
```

I need:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 PHOTOS
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="numNav">1 2 3 4 5 6 7</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.numNav {
    display: inline-block;
}
.numNav:after {
    content: "PHOTOS";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: [?](http://jsfiddle.net/5ss16n93/)

Comment: Once possible reason for "photos" to flow on to the next line is that `numNav` isn't wide enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `white-space: nowrap;` like:

```css
.numNav {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.numNav:after {
  content: "PHOTOS";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="numNav">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 </div>
```

Assume you are refering to smaller resolutions/windows. Cause in other cases works as it suppose.

Example without `whitespace: nowrap` and small width:

```css
.numNav {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}

.numNav:after {
    content: "PHOTOS";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="numNav">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 </div>
```

Same example this time using `whitespace: nowrap`:

```css
.numNav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.numNav:after {
  content: "PHOTOS";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="numNav">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 </div>
```

Comment: As notulysses' fiddle shows, the code the OP provided doesn't result in the output stated.

Comment: I think OP refers to smaller windows/resolutions.

Comment: Added seperate examples to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex Char! The third example with width and white-space did the trick.